# Update at the end up a for-in-loop

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

I'm trying to get this loop to run through 1-27 of my list, but I think it's looping through my list and only giving me an output for the last item in the list.  I think I want it to update the variable every time it loops through.

I'm only getting the output for the '27' (the last item in the list) or if I remove them all, then I'll get the output for the '1'(see below).

Does anyone have any idea of how this is done?

```
var regionslist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27];

var justthisregion;
var pndsplusthisregion;
var test;

var regionsplusponds = function (regionslist){

      for (var i in regionslist) {
        justthisregion = finregions.remap([regionslist[i]],[1000],0);
      }
      pndsplusthisregion = justthisregion.add(justponds);

      if (pndsplusthisregion===2000) {
          test = finregions.remap([regionslist[i]],[2000])

      } else {
          test = finregions.remap([regionslist[i]],[999])
      }
      addToMap(test, {min:0, max:2000, palette:['ff0033','993366','003366'], opacity:0.5}, "Regions with Ponds");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing your loop too soon.  This is the **only** line being ran 27 times `justthisregion = finregions.remap([regionslist[i]],[1000],0);`.  So `justthisregion` will only end up holding whatever the last interation was.  Move your `}` down.

```
var regionsplusponds = function (regionslist){
  for (var i in regionslist)
  {
    justthisregion = finregions.remap([regionslist[i]],[1000],0);
    pndsplusthisregion = justthisregion.add(justponds);
    if (pndsplusthisregion===2000)
      test = finregions.remap([regionslist[i]],[2000]);
    else
      test = finregions.remap([regionslist[i]],[999]);
    addToMap(test, {min:0, max:2000, palette:['ff0033','993366','003366'], opacity:0.5}, "Regions with Ponds");
  } /* <-- this was your problem line */
};
```

Comment: I've adjusted the code, moving the close loop } the the appropriate place.  That took care of one problem, but I also replaced 'test' with 'finregions'  -- I want it to adjust (or update) that variable each time before running it through the loop again. Yet, I'm not sure that will do what I want it to.

Comment: Well that is a different question.  If this solved your original question then please select the check mark to accept it as solved, then create a new question.  I don't quiet understand your new question so it's best to start a new question and describe it in more detail.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, your loop isn't encompassing all of the logic you're trying to iterate on. Try this:

```
var regionsplusponds = function (regionslist){
    for (var i in regionslist) {
        justthisregion = finregions.remap([regionslist[i]],[1000],0);
        pndsplusthisregion = justthisregion.add(justponds);
    if (pndsplusthisregion===2000){
        test = finregions.remap([regionslist[i]],[2000])}
    else{
        test = finregions.remap([regionslist[i]],[999])}
    addToMap(test, {min:0, max:2000, palette:['ff0033','993366','003366'], opacity:0.5}, "Regions with Ponds");}
};
```

Your for loop was reassigning justthisregion 27 times and then moving on to run the rest of the code just once. I moved the closing curly bracket of the for loop from after this line:

```
justthisregion = finregions.remap([regionslist[i]],[1000],0);}
```

to after this line:

```
addToMap(test, {min:0, max:2000, palette:['ff0033','993366','003366'], opacity:0.5}, "Regions with Ponds");}
```

That should work.

Comment: Yeah, that's **exactly** what I said 20 minutes prior to you.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I started writing that and went on to something else. When I came back and finished it and submitted it, I saw that you'd already submitted. Don't be angry, we can all be right.